# Trouble in search in grocery CRUD, search by one field with no results

Tags: grocery-crud

Trouble in search in grocery CRUD,  search by one field with no results , then I cannot get the original results back, "clear filtering" does not work, and refresh page will auto hide all results. Thanks!
Here is my code:

```
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

    $crud->set_table('p_user');
    $crud->where('parentid', $parent_id);

    $crud->required_fields('name');
    $crud->columns('name','password','email','type');

    $output = $crud->render();
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the code:

```
$crud->where('parentid', $parent_id);
```

Did you include the $parent_id to the URL? So for example if you have

http://www.example.com/main/test

it has to be: http://www.example.com/main/test/345 or something like that. So in your case I think this will solve your problem:

```
if (!empty($parent_id)) {
    $crud->where('parentid', $parent_id);
}
```